# How to change file extension ".ipa" to ".zip" in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I have to change file extension from ".ipa" to ".zip". Code following:

```
var filePath = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\abc.ipa";    
var result = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".zip");
File.Move(filePath, Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".zip"));
```

But this code throw an exception "Could not find file 'D\DemoProject\VCM2.ipa'.". And this file already in this mapPath. Is this have any wrong in this code?

Comment: Does your worker process have read/write access to the file?

Comment: full exception please?

Comment: I have tried code and it's ok when the input file is .rar and some other extension, but not ok when input file is .ipa. Do you have any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is your code `ChangeExtension` code duplicated?

```
var result = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".zip");
File.Move(filePath, Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".zip"));
```

may work if it was...

```
var result = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".zip");
File.Move(filePath, result);
```

Maybe not though. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: I have tried code and it's ok when the input file is .rar and some other extension, but not ok when input file is .ipa. Do you have any way to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried a less clean workaround using `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`? Otherwise - are you sure the file actually exists? Have you tried debugging and checking the path that's having trouble?

Comment: I have tried for other file .ipa and it's ok. Because my .ipa file is not correct. Thank you to help me about this.